Http Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type , Cannot consume content type
I added a new get API in my controller of a Rest service, there already have 2 APIs. The API is like below:
    @GET
    @Path("/alert")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Response getAlert(@NonNull @Context HttpServletRequest servletRequest,
                      @NonNull @QueryParam("merchantId") String merchantId,
                      Map<String, String> requestContext);

But when I tried to access it with following url
https://example.com/alert?merchantId=A3C1N4PUSVRODK

The following error returns:
{
    "code": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Cannot consume content type"
}

This is the way I used in code to request the url
await axios.get(url, {
        headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
});

The previous API in this controller works well in this way, can anyone help to answer what's wrong here?
When I tried to instead axios.get with fetch as follow, the API can return correctly.
await fetch(url, {
        headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
});

But still same error when I access the URL in my browser https://example.com/alert?merchantId=A3C1N4PUSVRODK

Try removing the Content-Type header from your Axios request. Since GET requests usually don't have a request body, explicitly setting the Content-Type header might be unnecessary and causing the server to reject the request.

@RavinaSarda Thanks. But there was same error  when I removed the content-type in the axios.get request. What confused me is even the fetch method works in website, but when I tried to access the URL in my browser directly, there was same error. So I guess maybe there is something wrong in the server side

Seems this is caused by the parameter type Map . After changing method to post or change it to a String type, the issue was resolved. But I didn't find any documentation regard it.
